# Can eigenvalues be expressed in terms of geometric relations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $3$ by 3 matrix with each row being a unit vector in
the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then can the eigenvalues of $AA^{t}$ be expressed
in terms of some geometric relations or geometric quantities among the row vectors of $A$
in the unit sphere? Thanks a lot.

Comment: if the rows are orthogonal then the eigenvalues are all equal to 1.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker That is correct and thank you for your comment. But how about rows that are not orthogonal? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The term  "*geometric*'' usually refers to something that is independent of the Euclidean coordinates.  The rows of $A$ are not geometric  in this sense.

Here is a  dynamical interpretation of the eigenvalues. This is geometric in the sense that it is independent of coordinates. I'll assume $A$ is generic. Then the surface $E=(AA^tx,x)=1$  $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ is an ellipsoid in $\bR^3$.

Think of the  sphere $\Sigma_t=\{\Vert x\Vert=t\}$ as  a moving wave front generated by a *ping!* at the origin, at time $t=0$. This  wave front will become tangent to $E$ at three moments of time $t_1<t_2< t_3$. The eigenvalues of $AA^t$ are $t_1^{-2}, t_2^{-2}, t_3^{-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the case in the comment (orthogonal rows $\Leftrightarrow$ unit eigenvalues), another simple case is where the three row vectors lie in a plane. The angle between the $i$th-row and the $j$-th row is $\theta_{ij}$. One eigenvalue is zero, the other two are
$$\tfrac{3}{2} \pm\sqrt{ \cos^2 \theta_{12}+ \cos^2  \theta_{13}+ \cos^2  \theta_{23}-\tfrac{3}{4}}.$$
The fully general case has expressions that are very much more complicated.